# Is it possible to step outside of the current TransactionScope and insert data

Tags: .net, database, transactions, transactionscope

Consider the following:

```
using (var outerScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    InsertDataInTableOne();
    InsertDataInTableTwo();
    InsertDataInTableThree();
    outerScope.Complete();
}
```

Now I want to have `InsertDataInTableOne` to be run outside of the `outerScope` transaction. This is a simplified representation, as the `TransactionScope` is created several calls up the chain, so I can't just put the call to `InsertDataInTableOne` outside of the `TransactionScope` creation.

I also know this might not be a good practice, and we're working on a decent fix. But we need this quick fix at this moment.

```
using (var outerScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var innerScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        InsertDataInTableOne();
        innerScope.Complete();
    }
    InsertDataInTableTwo();
    InsertDataInTableThree();
    outerScope.Complete();
}
```

That didn't work. I even tried with creating a `TransactionScope` with `Suppress` first, and then the `RequiresNew`.

So is it possible to insert data immediately in the database, effectively ignoring the fact that you are in a `TransactionScope`?

The connection is made outside of these methods (actually, when entering the service that is called).

Comment: What you have *should* work, assuming that a: you remember to complete the two transactions (your current code does not show this; there is no `innerScope.Complete();` or `outerScope.Complete();`), and b: the connections involved are created / opened *inside* their respective methods (so inside `InsertDataInTableOne` etc). Can you clarify what happens currently? And can you clarify where the connections are created / opened?

Comment: Forgot the Complete methods :) The connections are not created inside the methods, so that might be it? We are using NHibernate, so maybe we can do something with the Session and/or SessionFactory?

Comment: yeah, `TransactionScope` is fussy about when connections are created/opened. I can't advise on NHibernate, I'm afraid - I don't use it enough to give a qualified answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but you never know. The problem lies with a custom company-framework. The implementation makes it hard to have nested transactions, I believe. We fixed it now by removing the outer transaction (which is several layers up) and creating two separate transactions in our block:

```
using (var scopeOne = new TransactionScope())
{
    InsertDataInTableOne();
    scopeOne.Complete();
}

using (var scopeTwo = new TransactionScope())
{
    InsertDataInTableTwo();
    InsertDataInTableThree();
    scopeTwo.Complete();
}
```

Again, this is a solution very specific to our code. Using `RequiresNew` should normally do the trick. So if it doesn't work, maybe look into your own code first ;)

Another reason why I'm not a huge fan of do-it-all-company-frameworks.